# adding metaData to json responses in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, metadata

how would I go about adding meta data to a json response in rails 3.2?
Is there some way to access the model metadata and inclue that? ie. the field name, and the data type.

Something like the following:

```
{
"metaData":{
  "columns":[
     {
        "dataIndex":"id",
        "text":"User ID",
        "type":"integer"
     },
     {
        "dataIndex":"name",
        "text":"User Name",
        "type":"string"
     },
     {
        "dataIndex":"birthday",
        "format":"dd-mmm-yy",
        "text":"Birthday",
        "type":"datetime"
     }
  ]
},
"data":[
  {
     "id":1,
     "name":"Queen Elizabeth",
     "birthday":"1533-09-07T06:33:39Z"
  },
  {
     "id":2,
     "name":"Queen Elizabeth II",
     "birthday":"1926-04-21T02:40:00Z"
  }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model class will have a [`columns`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-columns) method that returns an array of column objects. You could extract most of your metadata from that:

```
metas = Model.columns.map { |c| c.as_json.slice('name', 'type') }
```

then you can add that to your response.

Comment: .columns is exactly what i was looking for thanks.  so obvious too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably build that up with something like [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder)

There's a good railscast episode on how to use it http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder